# Usar jquery en un elemento insertado desde php con ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

He insertado un select de un php con ajax en otro php que es el index. Este es el index de donde cojo los dato.

```
<?php 
include 'conexion.php';
$msg ="";
$tipo= $_POST['tipo']??"";
$sql = "SELECT marca.idmarca as id,marca.marca as marca
from marca, producto, modelo
where producto.modelo = modelo.idmodelo
and modelo.marca = marca.idmarca
and producto.tipo = '$tipo'";
$consulta = $conn->query($sql);
$msg .= "<select id=\"marc\">";
$msg .= "<option value=\"\">Selecciona una marca</option>";

while($fila = $consulta->fetch()){
$msg .= "<option value=\"".$fila['id']."\">".$fila['marca']."</option>";

}
$msg .= "</select>";
echo $msg;
?>
```

Y al coger el id del select en el jquery no me hace nada.
El enlace de jquery esta en el index.php.

```
//Codigo jquery

$("#marc").change(function(){
 var tipo = $(this).val();
 alert(tipo);

});
```

Comment: ¿El change está dentro de `ready`?

Comment: si esta dentro del  $(document).ready(function()

Comment: El problema al parecer es que `DOMContentLoaded` se dispara **antes** que se el select se genere mediante PHP. Podrías dejar el `<select>` vacío directamente en el HTML y luego llenarlo con el resultset.

Comment: qué es el resultset perdona es que soy novato todavía

Comment: Lo que trae la consulta de la base de datos. Haz lo que te digo para que pruebes. Pon el `<select>` directamente en el HTML y más abajo solo lo llenas con los datos.

Comment: vale si lo hice así y ya me funciona.Muchas gracias.

Comment: @BorjaSanchez ¿Pones la respuesta o la pongo yo?

Comment: ponla que seguro que la explicas tú mejor, de verdad muchas gracias

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Cuando se tratan elementos dinámicos se tiene usar el `on`, ya sea para clik,change, etc.

Prueba usando:

```
$("#marc").on('change', function(){
  var tipo = $(this).val();
  alert(tipo);
});
```

Comment: Es lo mismo que ha hecho el OP. jQuery te permite hacer atajos en lugar de `.on`.

Comment: @GustavoGarcía, no, no es lo mismo. jQuery utiliza funciones diferentes en base al DOM. En este caso el input no estaba creado cuando el DOM terminó de cargarse, entonces jQuery no puede encontrar el elemento con un simple change.

Comment: no no me funciona tampoco con el on.

Comment: @user2930137 Eso es obvio pero en ningún momento me refiero a eso. Lo que estoy diciendo es que `.change` **es un atajo** para `.on('change')`. Consulta la documentación para que salgas de dudas: *This method **is a shortcut** for .on( "change", handler )*.

Comment: pero como es dinámico el `select` se tiene que colocar el `on`. Puedes probarlo.

Comment: @Acd sería genial que agregues esa información en la respuesta

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que el id `marc` no esta cargado en el `DOM` cuando quieres usar tu función:

```js
// No sabe la id #marc
$('#marc').on('change', function(){
  
  var tipo = $(this).val();
  alert(tipo);  
});

function ajaxSelect(){
  
  $('body').append('<select id="marc"><option value="">Selecciona</option><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option></select>');
}

$('button').click(ajaxSelect);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Crear Ajax Select</button>
```

Lo que puedes hacer es una lo que te ha dicho @GustavoGarcia en el [commentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/54980/usar-jquery-en-un-elemento-insertado-desde-php-con-ajax#comment-98243) o también puedes [`delegar`](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) el evento:

```js
// Delegamos el evento
$(document).on('change', '#marc', function(){
  
  var tipo = $(this).val();
  console.log(tipo);
  
});

function ajaxSelect(){
  
  $('body').append('<select id="marc"><option value="">Selecciona</option><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option></select>');
}

$('button').click(ajaxSelect);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Crear Ajax Select</button>
```

Comment: Esta es la respuesta correcta. La delegación del handler siempre va a funcionar, sin recurrir a la salvedad de poner el elemento select en duro